# correcting effects with Tukey's test

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, emmeans, tukey

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
m <- lmer(angle ~ recipe*temp + (1|replicate), data=cake)
```

I'm interested in the simple effect of each recipe (not pairwise comparisons) so based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518034/get-significance-of-simple-effects-with-emtrends)

```
out.emtrends <- emtrends(m, pairwise~recipe, var="temp")
emtr <- as.data.frame(out.emtrends$emtrends)
tvalues <- emtr$temp.trend/emtr$SE
dfs <- emtr$df
pvalues <- 2*pt(-abs(tvalues), dfs)
```

Now I would like to use Tukey's test for correcting my p-value; is this possible or is Tukey's test only appropriate for differences between treatments?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: `summary(out.emtrends, infer=rep(TRUE,2))$p.value` will give you unadjusted p-values.  You're right that Tukey is for pairwise comparisons, not for multiple-comparisons corrections on a set of values.  Check out `?p.adjust` for other options (Bonferroni, Bonferroni-Holm, etc etc)

Comment: I don’t quite agree with @BenBolker ‘s answer. See the answer I posted.  To get unadjusted tests, use ‘adjust = “none”‘

Comment: I'm trying to interpret what the OP said, which is "I'm interested in the trend for each recipe", i.e. they're not actually trying to get pairwise comparisons. (I started out writing a comment that's a lot like your answer, then I thought that's not what they actually wanted ...)

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear".  If you can explain more clearly whether you want pairwise tests or simply tests of each group individually, that would help.

Comment: @BenBolker, I'm trying to test the slopes of each recipe indeividually, so your code above does what I was looking for. And I suspected that Tukey might not be the test for this so I'll check out the other options then. Thanks!

Comment: if two more people vote to reopen I'll post my answer.

Comment: @BenBolker have at it.

Answer (score 3):

When using `pairwise`, the adjustment actually *defaults* to Turkey. You will see it in the annotations below the contrast results if you simply display it via

```
out.emtrends
```

*However*, there is one exception, and that is when there are only two estimates in the family being compared. In that case, there is only one comparison. In that case, there is no multiplicity and thus no need for any kind of adjustment for multiplicity.